# Is it possible to store in variable something with a class and z-index?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, navigation, z-index

In jQuery, on mobile, I have nav links that I would like them to shuffle position when clicked that I currently have as:

```
const workBtn = $('#work .nav-btn');
const aboutBtn = $('#about .nav-btn');
const contactBtn = $('#contact .nav-btn');
```

In html, my buttons are part of their parents sections and are layered on-top of each other using z-indexes. For mobile size I don't know what order the three links could be when clicked, but still want to target them based on their z-indexes. Is it possible to store in variables something that only looks for the class 'nav-btn' and what z-index it has?

Something like?

```
const middleBtn = $('.nav-btn').attr('z-index', '4');
```

Comment: `z-index` is a css attribute, not a direct attribute.  there is the `css()` method you should take a look at.  http://api.jquery.com/css/#css1

Comment: Technically if you are trying to get what the z-index is, you would not pass in the second argument to `css()` either.

Comment: `$('.nav-btn').each(function(i, e){ var t = $(e); if(t.css('zIndex') === '4'){ /* do stuff */ });`

Answer (score 0):

Gets css attribute:
`const middleBtn = $('.nav-btn').css('z-index');`

Sets css attribute
`const middleBtn = $('.nav-btn').css('z-index', '4');`